# Request-Promise how to global catch error

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, request

I'm using Node.JS and request-promise.
I have to send requests through proxy and change proxy on error (if it'll stop working). I don't want to catch error every time on every request. I want it globally. How to do it?

```
async function getTest(){
   let res = rp('htt://someurl..')
        .then((body) => {
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            if (error.error.code === 'ECONNRESET') {
                console.log('gettext proxy error');
                return 'proxyerror';
            }
        });
   return await res;
}
```

Can I somehow bind .on event waiting for errors from request-promise globally?

I don't want sth like this:

```
async function getTest(){
    let res = rp('htt://someurl..')
        .then((body) => {
            rp('htt://someurl2..')
                .then((body) => {
                    rp('htt://someurl3..')
                        .then((body) => {
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                            if (error.error.code === 'ECONNRESET') {
                                console.log('gettext proxy error');
                                return 'proxyerror';
                            }
                        });
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    if (error.error.code === 'ECONNRESET') {
                        console.log('gettext proxy error');
                        return 'proxyerror';
                    }
                });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            if (error.error.code === 'ECONNRESET') {
                console.log('gettext proxy error');
                return 'proxyerror';
            }
        });
    return await res;
}
```

Comment: If it's the same error logic for every single one, define a function you can use anywhere you need to catch the errors.

Comment: @MinusFour URL will change and functions in 'then' too so how

Comment: `rp(myNewURL).then(myOtherThen).catch(theErrorFunctionIWillUseEverywhere)`

Comment: Why do you want to catch errors globally, you hardly can handle them there? What do you want to do with the errors? And what do you want the functions that use `getTest` to do when an error occurs?

Comment: I want to separate handling errors: due to not working proxy and due to not available page. Now I have to do it on every request separately. I don't want one error function for every request. I want only 'run' additional function (change proxy) on connection error on any of requests.

Comment: I updated the question why it's wrong

Comment: @Davidos you don't have to. The `rp` promises need to be returned (e.g. `return rp(..)`) and you only need the error handler on the first one.

Comment: @MinusFour I'm unable to do this if i use inside then this: $('...').each(functionn(){ return rp... }); it doesn't work